# Is it possible to use the present perfect tense with the time marker "last night"?

Tags: tense, usage

The ground is all wet. It must **have rained** last night.
Why is the present perfect tense used in the second sentence if there is a 'last night' time marker?

Comment: The ground **is** all wet...

Comment: It's because of the modal **must**.

Comment: @TimR - The ground is all wet, and I can see that the surface of a puddle is disturbed by falling drops. It **must be** raining [now].

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's present tense. See answer.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, the present perfect cannot be used in a clause with a time-marker that excludes the present. But this isn't a present perfect. We have to use the auxiliary "have" +  past participle to form the past with **must**:

> Many palm trees are blown over here. The hurricane **must have struck** here a few days *ago*.  <sup>grammatical</sup>
>
> I *have seen* him four days *ago*. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

Comment: Because of "*Normally...*", this answer incorrectly implies that "must have rained" is a perfect tense.

Comment: @gotube  The answer says "...we have to use the auxiliary 'have' + past participle to form the past with **must** ". But for people who infer, I will double down on the past.

Comment: Great! I'd upvote this if it didn't start with "normally", which implies the present perfect can be used with a finished time expression in other contexts.

Comment: @gotube  But the present perfect *can* be used with "finished time expressions" (or in my phrase, "time-markers that exclude the present") in some odd cases involving historical-present narratives.

Comment: Neat! Can you give me an example?

Comment: @gotube Maybe I should call it the "telescoped present" not "historical present". Let's say we have a story very like *The Christmas Carol* by Dickens, in which a psychopomp is showing our Scrooge in a troubled dream the future effects of his actions: "There's the grave of the little boy; he has died of malnutrition. And there's his father, the employee you *have cast off a mere three weeks earlier*. The family were living hand-to-mouth and they have been in freefall ever since."  The time-telescoping allows present perfect "have cast off" despite "three weeks earlier".

Comment: While that example does have both the present perfect and a time-marker that excludes the present in the same sentence, the time marker doesn't modify the present perfect expression. The main clause there is, "*And there's his father **a mere three weeks earlier**." The present perfect clause "*you have cast off*" is an identifying relative clause that modifies "employee", which is in apposition to "his father", and that phrase has nothing to do with "*a mere three weeks earlier*" structurally or semantically. Present perfect truly can only be modified by phrases that include the present.

Comment: @gotube:  "the employee you have cast off a mere three weeks earlier" does stand in apposition with "his father", as you say; "you have cast off a mere three weeks earlier" is indeed a restrictive/identifying relative clause modifying "employee"; but "a mere three weeks earlier" does *not* modify "father"; rather it is adverbial and modifies "have cast off".  I could have written "And there, beside the grave, is his father, the employee..."  It is not "And there, three weeks earlier, is his father ..."

Comment: Oops. I misread the context, and you're right that "a mere three weeks earlier" here directly modifies the present perfect. To me, that's bad grammar. Maybe it was acceptable back in Dickens's day, but I don't think it would get past an editor today. Anyway, +1!

Answer (score 3):

No, you can never use present perfect with a finished past time phrase, such as "last night".

Your example sentence has the structure *[ "must have" + past participle ]*. *This is not present perfect*.

The structure of present perfect is *[ "have/has" + past participle ]*. Notice that "have/has" means the form of "have" must be present simple. The "have" in your sentence is not present simple, but base form. We know this both because it comes after a modal verb, and because the present simple form of "have" with the third person singular subject "it" is "has", not "have".

Structures like *[ "must/could/would/etc have" + past participle ]* always and only refer to finished past times, so they can use finished past time expressions like "last night". They have no similarities in meaning to any perfect tense.

Comment: Can I use "should" in this structure?

Comment: @Elizabeth Yes, "should have" + past participle is the same structure.